# Can you transfer directly to an image without using an intermediary buffer

Tags: vulkan

If I've allocated an image in memory that IS NOT host-visible then I get a staging buffer that IS host-visible so I can write to it. I memcpy into that buffer, and then I do a vkCmdCopyBufferToImage.

However let's say we're running on hardware where the device-local image memory is also host-visible, is it more efficient and better to just memcpy into this image memory? In what image layout does the image need to be in if memcpying straight into it? Transfer destination? How would this work mip levels? In the copy buffer to image method you specify each mip level, but if memcpying in how do you do this? Or do just not? And just do the extra copy to the host-visible staging buffer and then do copy buffer to image?

Answer (score 3):

`VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL` arrangement is implementation-dependent and unexposed.

`VK_IMAGE_TILING_LINEAR` arrangement is whatever `vkGetImageSubresourceLayout` says it is.

The device-local host-visible memory on current desktop GPUs have a specific purpose. But anyway, you wouldn't have access to most of the GPU capacity this way.

If you do it the right way™, then there is already only one transfer. The `memcpy` is unnecessary. Either you build your linear image directly in Vulkan's memory, or you cast your arbitrary memory to Vulkan with `VK_EXT_external_memory_host`.

> In what image layout does the image need to be in if memcpying straight into it?

Host writes are either `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PREINITIALIZED` or `VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL`.

> How would this work mip levels?

`vkGetImageSubresourceLayout()` gives `pLayout->offset` and `pLayout->size` saying where subresource starts and ends.

Comment: Note that implementations do not *have* to offer much functionality for `LINEAR` tiled images. The only functionality that Vulkan *requires* that they offer is that you can do image-to-image copies with them. You don't have to be able to sample from them, even if they're able to be put into device-local storage.

Comment: When you say this: "If you do it the right way™, then there is already only one transfer. The memcpy is unnecessary. Either you build your linear image directly in Vulkan's memory," Let's say you're streaming an image from disk, where do you read the buffer to? The only way I can think of is to read it to a staging buffer, then copy it to device-local memory.

Comment: @Zebrafish Obviously the count of copies implies any copy you might do outside Vulkan. If someone sends you the file with email, that is like extra N copies with N being proportional with the amount of routers along the way. On Vulkan side there should be only at most one copy. You operate directly with the staging buffer (and not unnecessarily copy from another buffer to staging buffer like the Q proposes). If there is device-side host-visible memory, then that can be used directly without staging buffer, which is particularly useful for `VkBuffer`s (which do not have Tiling like `VkImages`).

Comment: @Zebrafish PS: And the new extension `VK_EXT_host_image_copy` deals with the annoying parts of handling `VkImages`.